# Showing a set is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Show $T$ $=$ $\bigcup_{x \in S} [x-1,x+1]$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I have tried using the definition of measurability (using intersection of T and its complement with arbitrary subsets of the real line) to reduce the problem to a statement about S being measurable, to no avail.

I do not even know another way to proceed. Any help?

Comment: If $K$ is compact and contained in $S$, can you use it to define a compact subset $K'$ of $T$? Similarly, if $U$ is open and contains $S$, can you use it to define an open that contains $T$? If you can further ensure that if $K$ is "close" to $S$ then $K'$ is close to $T$, and similarly for $U$, then you are done.

Comment: I do not see any obvious way to take a compact set of S to T. A canonical thing to try would be taking the same union over K, but I see no reason that should be compact.